# Send an e-mail to facebook

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

I am trying to send an e-mail which contains an attachment (an image) to my facebook account (used to post this image on my page's wall).

The e-mail sent perfectly but nothing is shown on my wall.

If I send it directly through Gmail, it works perfectly. What I am doing wrong ?

Here is my code :

```
private static final String HOST = "smtp.gmail.com";
private static final String USERNAME = "myusername"; // Without @gmail.com
private static final String PASSWORD = "mypassword";

private static final Properties PARAMETERS = new Properties() {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L; {
        put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        put("mail.smtp.host", HOST);
        put("mail.smtp.user", USERNAME);
        put("mail.smtp.password", PASSWORD);
        put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
        put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    }
};

// Some code...

final File newest = new File(COMICS_DIR, COMICS_DIR.list().length - 1 + ".png"); // The file I want to upload.
final Session session = Session.getInstance(PARAMETERS);
final MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(USERNAME));
message.addRecipient(RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(FACEBOOK_MAIL)); // My facebook mail.
message.setSubject(title);
final Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
final BodyPart body = new MimeBodyPart();
body.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(new FileDataSource(newest)));
body.setFileName(newest.getName());
multipart.addBodyPart(body);
message.setContent(multipart);
final Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
transport.connect(HOST, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
```

Thanks for your time and sorry for my bad english.

EDIT : I have the same error for Tumblr but it works for Twitpics.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Replace

```
final Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
final BodyPart body = new MimeBodyPart();
body.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(new FileDataSource(newest)));
body.setFileName(newest.getName());
multipart.addBodyPart(body);
message.setContent(multipart);
```

with

```
final Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
multipart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(new FileDataSource(newest)));
multipart.setDisposition(Part.ATTACHMENT);
multipart.setFileName(newest.getName());
message.setContent(multipart);
message.saveChanges();
```

Comment: Thanks but I fixed my problem using : `body.setHeader("Content-Type", "image/png");`. I thumb up for your help ;)